# 一括処理をするクラスメソッドに対するRspecの書き方

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

「一定期間以上 既読状態なら未読に戻す」というクラスメソッドへのRSpecを書きたいのですが動作しません。

テストはこのように書き

```
  let(:company){ Company.create }
  describe ".remove_old_read" do
    before{ Timecop.freeze(Time.local(2014,10,10)) }
    after{ Timecop.return }
    context "既読で3ヶ月以上前なら" do
      before do
        company.update_attributes(read: true, read_at: Time.new(2014,7,9))
        Company.remove_old_read
      end
      it "未読にする" do
        expect(company.read).to eq(false)
      end
    end
  end
```

対するメソッドはこのように書いています。

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.remove_old_read
    Company.where("read_at < ?", Time.zone.now - 3.month).each do |c|
      c.update_attributes({read: false}) #if c.read 
    end
  end
end
```

どこが間違えているのでしょうか？
特にクラスメソッドの呼び出し方法が自信ありません…。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

僕が書くとしたらこんな感じですかねー。

```
describe ".remove_old_read" do
  context "既読で3ヶ月以上前なら" do
    before do
      company.update_attributes(read: true, read_at: Time.local(2014, 7, 9))
    end
    after{ Timecop.return }
    it "未読にする" do
      Timecop.freeze(Time.local(2014, 10, 10)) 
      expect { Company.remove_old_read }.to change{ company.reload.read }.from(true).to(false)
    end
  end
end
```

`Company.remove_old_read`はテストコード上は`company`と全く関連のないメソッドになっています。
なので`company`は`reload`してあげないとDBの状態とテストコード上の状態がシンクしません。
たぶんここがポイントじゃないかなと思います。

それから、`context "既読で3ヶ月以上前なら"`って書いているなら、Timecopを使ったシステム日時の変更はこのcontextブロックの中で書いてあげましょう。
また、`remove_old_read`の近くで変更したほうが「これは2014-10-10にremove_old_readするんだな」というのが見た目にわかりやすくていいと思います。

あと`change`マッチャについてはこちらを参照してください。

- http://qiita.com/jnchito/items/2e79a1abe7cd8214caa5#change--from--to--by

参考になれば幸いです。

#### 別解

read_atを3ヶ月前の日時で更新すればTimecopはいらないですね。

```
describe ".remove_old_read" do
  context "既読で3ヶ月以上前なら" do
    before do
      # 3ヶ月前ピッタリだとタイミングによっては条件に合致しないかもしれないので、
      # さらに1分追加しておく。
      company.update_attributes(read: true, read_at: 3.months.ago - 1.minute)
    end
    it "未読にする" do
      expect { Company.remove_old_read }.to change{ company.reload.read }.from(true).to(false)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: 詳しい解説有難うございます。クラスメソッドでインスタンスの状態が変わった場合は `instance_name.reload` という書き方ができるんですね。勉強になります。